# npm install: how to skip already installed global packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

In npm, how do I skip the installation of packages already installed in global repository?

For example:

**package.json**:

```
{
   "dependencies" : {
      "ytsr" : "",
      "cheerio" : "",
      "express" : "",
      "request" : ""
   }
}
```

In the above example I already have `express` and `request` installed in **global** repository. I want to install only `ytsr` and `cheerio` packages locally.

Comment: You better use project packages instead of global ones because it's easier to manage when using a different machine.

Comment: Most of my projects are private, they won't be deplyoed.

Comment: So, just remove the packages you don't want to be installed from the package.json file.